# Directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I am using docker compose to up my container which works fine but when I try to go to the `http://localhost:8080/` I get the following error:

> 2023/07/18 07:22:07 [error] 12#12: *6 directory index of
> "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.31.0.1, server: _, request:
> "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
> 172.31.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2023:07:22:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 196 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

And here is my `nginx` config file named:  `phirater.test.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name phirater.test;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    index index.php index.htm index.html;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/phirater.test-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/phirater.test-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

When I try to hit the following: `http://localhost:8080/composer.json` it displays the content of the files but `http://localhost:8080` return with the error mentioned above.
What I am doing wrong here?

User permissons are like this inside the container:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 1000 1000   1369 Jul 13 12:46 Dockerfile*
drwxr-xr-x  13 1000 1000   4096 Nov 16  2022 app/
-rwxr-xr-x   1 1000 1000   1635 Nov 16  2022 artisan*
-rw-rw-rw-   1 1000 1000   1321 Jul 13 12:45 bitbucket-pipelines.yml
drwxr-xr-x   3 1000 1000   4096 Nov 16  2022 bootstrap/
-rw-r--r--   1 1000 1000   1419 Nov 16  2022 bower.json
-rw-r--r--   1 1000 1000   3393 Jun 14 05:19 composer.json
-rw-r--r--   1 1000 1000 410926 Jul 10 10:34 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x   2 1000 1000   4096 Jul 13 12:45 config/
drwxr-xr-x   4 1000 1000   4096 Nov 16  2022 database/
drwxr-xr-x   3 1000 1000   4096 Jul  5 02:24 docker-compose/
-rw-rw-rw-   1 1000 1000   4114 Jul 13 12:45 gulpfile.js
drwxr-xr-x 377 1000 1000  16384 Jun  8 09:26 node_modules/
-rw-r--r--   1 1000 1000    394 Jun 14 05:05 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 1000 1000    724 Jul 18 06:42 phirater.test.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 1000 1000   5480 Jul 13 12:45 php-fpm.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 1000 1000     97 Nov 16  2022 phpspec.yml
lrwxrwxrwx   1 1000 1000     18 Jun 13 06:31 phpunit -> vendor/bin/phpunit*
-rw-r--r--   1 1000 1000   1860 Jun 14 05:05 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x   8 1000 1000   4096 Nov 16  2022 public/
drwxr-xr-x   5 1000 1000   4096 Nov 16  2022 resources/
-rw-r--r--   1 1000 1000    560 Nov 16  2022 server.php
-rw-r--r--   1 1000 1000    332 Jul 13 07:00 start-container.sh
drwxr-xr-x   8 1000 1000   4096 Jul 13 10:01 storage/
-rw-r--r--   1 1000 1000    308 Jul 11 11:43 supervisord.conf
drwxr-xr-x   7 1000 1000   4096 Jul 13 12:45 tests/
drwxr-xr-x  81 1000 1000   4096 Jul  5 05:22 vendor/
```

I tried the solution on various similar question here on SO but none worked.

Comment: Why have you set root to `/var/www/html/public` but have also included `/public` in other directives? What are your Docker volume mounts?

Comment: @Phil that was a mistake, already corrected that in the question.

Comment: And your volume mounts?

Comment: @Phil     `volumes:
      - phirater-l51:/var/www/html`

Comment: Seems to me that there is no `index.php` file, so by default nginx wants to display the list of files, which is not permitted.  Based on what you say if you can view the content of composer.json, your mount mapping is incorrect.  Your project root should be on `/var/www/html` not `/var/www/html/public`.

Comment: @Leroy already tried `/var/www/html` but the same result.

Comment: Do you have any `index.*` files in your `public` directory?

Comment: try to change , fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; to be like this fastcgi_pass php:9000;

Answer (score 1):

You're using a named host so you'd need the request URL to match, ie `http://phirater.test:8080/`.

The server handling your `http://localhost:8080/` request is the default one which is why the error mentions `/var/www/html` and not `/var/www/html/public`.

You can use your named host by editing your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)), however I recommend since it's unlikely you're running nginx with multiple named tenants to simply overwrite the **default** config.

```yaml
volumes:
  - phirater-l51/phirater.test.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  - phirater-l51:/var/www/html
```